# Why is this jquery script not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So I have a website that allows a user to enter a link and it then extracts information and places it into a list for them.

Now everything was working fine until yesterday when my web hosting partner done some upgrades.  I know that mysql & php have been upgrading but am not sure what else.

First I had issues that I could not log into the DB (had to drop and recreate users).
Then an issue with PHP serialise for JSON (needed a code change).
Then a 412 invalid precondition error (needed a special rule set up by the hosting partner).
And now last of all a jquery script has stopped working.  But I have no idea as to why.  It worked before, but maybe that was luck (I am not so experienced in this).

Anyway, what happens is

1. User enters a link.
2. jquery calls a link which returns JSON.
3. The JSON is parsed and the web page updated with the results.
4. The user clicks on save and the data is entered into the DB.

using firebug and placing alerts in my javascript then I can see that Step 1, step 2 work fine.  The JSON returned is valid (I have verfied it with JSONlint) but step 3 does not work.  My script is below;

```
function getURLData(form)
{
    var listid = $('input#listid').val();
    var memberid = $('input#memberid').val();
    var link = $('input#link').val();
    var sendstr = "http://www.wishindex.com/ajax.php?link=\"" + link + "\"&listid=" + listid + "&memberid=" + memberid;

alert(sendstr);
        $.getJSON(sendstr,function(result)
        {   
            alert('inside');        
            if(result['Itemname'] != "")
            {
                alert('inside2');
                $('#itemname').val(result['Itemname']);
                $('#itemname').attr('readonly', 'true');
                $('#desc').val(result['Description']);
                $('#category').val(result['Category']);
                $('#category').attr('readonly', 'true');
                $('#price').val(result['Price']);
                $('#price').attr('readonly', 'true');
                $('#choosepicture').attr('onclick', 'window.open(\'http://www.wishindex.com/picture.php?link=' + result['Link'] + '\')');
                if (result['PictureLink'] != "")
                {
                    $('#picturelink').val(result['PictureLink']);
                    $('#picturelink').attr('readonly', 'true');                 
                }
                else
                    $('#choosepicture').removeAttr('disabled');

                $('#automatic').attr('value', 'true');      
                $('#currency').val(result['Currency']);
                $('#currency').attr('readonly', 'true');
            }
            else
            {           
                $('#automatic').attr('value', 'false');
                $('#manual').html('Please enter details manually');
                $('#choosepicture').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#choosepicture').attr('onclick', 'window.open(\'http://www.wishindex.com/picture.php?link=' + result['Link'] + '\')');
            }
        });
}
```

If I enable the alerts then I see the link called is correct, the JSON is valid (via firebug and calling the link manually) and that the alert('inside') & alert('inside2') are executed so it is reaching this segment of the code, but my html elements are not updated!

As I said, before the upgrade it was fine,  but maybe I have done something wrong, so any help would be appreciated as I have spent hours on this and can't find the issue.

My JSON response;

```
[{"ID":"","MemberID":"24","Listid":"41","Itemname":"LEGO Star Wars 9489: Endor Rebel Trooper and Imperial Trooper","Description":null,"NumberDesired":null,"NumberPurchased":null,"Category":{"0":"TOYS_AND_GAMES"},"Link":"\"http:\/\/www.amazon.co.uk\/LEGO-Star-Wars-9489-Imperial\/dp\/B005KISGAI\/ref=pd_rhf_gw_shvl1\"","PictureLink":{"0":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51fQnt%2BlppL._SL160_.jpg"},"Price":"9.89","Currency":"\u00a3","Priority":null,"SuggestedPurchaser":null,"ActualPurchaser":null,"PurchaseStatus":null,"Productid":"B005KISGAI","Site":"amazon.co.uk","DateAdded":null,"DatePurchased":null,"Domain":null,"Temp":["LEGO-Star-Wars-9489-Imperial","dp","B005KISGAI","ref=pd_rhf_gw_shvl1\""],"Error":"","Warning":null}]
```

You can call this to get a JSON result example

http://www.wishindex.com/ajax.php?link=%22http://www.amazon.co.uk/LEGO-Star-Wars-9489-Imperial/dp/B005KISGAI/ref=pd_rhf_gw_shvl1%22&listid=41&memberid=24

A working demo (as requested) can be found here;
http://www.wishindex.com/test_newitem.php?listid=41

To test;

1. Enter a product link from amazon.co.uk such as
   http://www.amazon.co.uk/LEGO-Star-Wars-9489-Imperial/dp/B005KISGAI/ref=pd_rhf_gw_shvl1
   into the link field
2. Click on get details and the rest of the fields should be populated
   automatically, but t hey are not.

Comment: could you show the json or part of it?

Comment: I think that you should post a live demo. Your hosting partner has done un update. Ok. But if the json result of ajax call is ok then server side is okay. If the client worked yesterday then the client is ok. So... at least one of your assumptions is wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is an object inside an array. so you should only be able to access the data like that: `result[0]['Itemname']` or do `result = result[0]` before you access it.

So it reaches 'inside2' because `result['Itemname']` is `undefined` which is `!= ""`

Comment: This is actually the issue.  The JSON shouldn't be an array, and it turns out that the change I made to get around the PHP problem (in ajax.php) was returning an array when it shouldn't have been.  Now I have changed it then it returns a none array and the fields are updated.  I still have some formatting issues to resolve, but that can be sorted easily.  Thanks.